# Apache Log issue on Webmin

Tags: apache, logging, webmin

I'm not sure when this issue first started but for at least 3 months I've not had any errors logging to the Apache log, despite knowing there are errors that should be going in there.

I'm using Webmin and I was going to set up a new log to store these errors but I'm not sure what I need to do in order to make it log Apache (PHP) errors.

I'm looking at the following site for instructions but it doesn't explicitly say anything about Apache errors and the last thing I want to do is mess with the server:

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/System_Logs